# custom view with overlapping

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I define layout row which I inflate and add view pragmatically to a linear layout.

I wanna something like this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKPmJ.png

Here is xml of my main activity where I am inflating the costume view row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.skw.customeviewdemo.MainActivity">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/inflate"
    android:text="inflate"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_container">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is my xml code of row which I am inflating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="its text view"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nameButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b;
    LinearLayout l1;
    Context context;
    Boolean isViewCreated = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final String Namearray[] = {"sagar", "ranjeet", "akash", "kate"};
        this.context = this;

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inflate);
        l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_container);

        createViews(Namearray);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(l1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && isViewCreated)
                {
                    l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void createViews(final String[] namearray)
    {
        for(int i=0;i < namearray.length;i++){
            final int j = i;
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_item,null);
            TextView button1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.nameButton);


            button1.setText("HELLO " + namearray[i]);
            button2.setText("Click to know my name ");

            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Hello " + namearray[j],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            view.setId(generateViewId());

            try {
                l1.addView(view);
                isViewCreated = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
        l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private static final AtomicInteger viewIdGenerator = new AtomicInteger(15000000);

    public static int generateViewId() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            return generateUniqueViewId();
        } else {
            return View.generateViewId();
        }
    }

    private static int generateUniqueViewId() {
        while (true) {
            final int result = viewIdGenerator.get();
            // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
            int newValue = result + 1;
            if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
            if (viewIdGenerator.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when I inflate row my image view get cutoff which I not want I tried with negative margin but it not work
here what it looks like
[custom overlapping row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBfIq.png)

what I do so I over lap image to above view?

Comment: without doing the coding on my end...the image view you want to be on top of the layout need to either be out of that relative view, or inside of another relative view under of the bottom layer. so > <RL></RL><RL></RL>

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your layout to this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="its text view"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nameButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

When you put in another row, that row needs to be pushed up so the android icon that is there now overlays it.

Comment: it may not work with your code bud. you might have to visit how your code is working....

Comment: is it a list view? the problem is when a new item is added, its being added onto of the other but in a vertical state. this will always cut off that logo.

Comment: i paste all working code, on button click it add views runtime, its not list view, i just inflate few views runtime

Comment: I think u need a separate view for the button you want to add on top of/in the middle of the other views.... then inflate when after you inflate each line.

Comment: its a pesky view tbh. try what I said before. one for the left hand side stuff and another for the right circles. inflate the left then right. the right side icons needs to be below (which in return makes it on top) of the left. hard to explain.